# Rule about solving congruences - modular arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When solving $ax \equiv b \mod c$, is it okay to replace $a$ with any $m$ where $m \equiv a$?

Comment: Yes, you can replace $a$ by any $a'$ such that $a'\equiv a\pmod{c}$.

Comment: Note that "$m\equiv a$" is meaningless --- there must be a modulus. If you meant $m\equiv a\pmod c$, then you're OK.

Comment: Note that if an answer is helpful, you may select one answer per question to "accept": you can do this by clicking on the "greyed-out" checkmark to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Soon, after you've reached 30 reputation points, you can upvote as many answers as you'd like to any given question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about what $ax \equiv b \pmod c$ means, i.e. there exists a $ q \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $ax = b + qc$ so if we have $a = m + qc$ Then substitution gives $$(m+qc)x = b + qc$$
and  $$mx = b + (q-qx)c$$
So $$mx \equiv b \pmod c$$